# Z-order of elements broken by -webkit-transform: translateZ

Tags: javascript, html, css, css-transforms

Can the hardware enforcing `-webkit-transform: translateZ(20px);` be used on some elements while the rest of the page has ordinary `z-index:10;`

I post this question since i have some issues with a sticky sidemenu which triggered some rendering issues on chrome and therefore was complemented with `-webkit-transform: translateZ(20px);`. Whilst the rest of the page still uses z-index, like [here](http://jsfiddle.net/Lx7T9/). The footer for instance is supposed to be covered by the sticky side menu while scrolled to the bottom, this used to work(before translateZ) but now the footer appears on top...

[image]
[image]
[image]

I have tried adding `translateZ(10px);` to the footer and divs wrapping the entire page without success, this is obviously not something i want to do since I only own the product with the side menu and not the rest of the page... I.e. footer...

In [this](http://jsfiddle.net/CP56H/20/) case: why does the footer appear on top of the red box?

Comment: The two properties are not related.

Comment: The properties are related in that you can use them to achieve a z-stacking. I.e. elements on top of eachother. The difference being that the transform triggers hardware rendering. Do you mean that the behaviour in terms of priority is undefined?

Comment: Basically, yes, but it's hard to see how a `transformZ` value in pixels will affect stacking order.

Comment: In the fiddle the footer shows on top because it has a higher z-index. And please use the CSS panel on jsfiddle